# Navigation Bar - Each button is at a seperate line, how do I fix that?

Tags: html, css

Demo: http://glados.cc/eJdemo/

My code:

```
<style type="text/css">
#home
{
display: block;
width: 40px;
height: 38px;
background: url("bar1.png") no-repeat 0 0;
}
#home:hover
{ 
background-position: 0 -38px;
}
#myplaces
{
display: block;
width: 123px;
height: 38px;
background: url("bar2.png") no-repeat 0 0;
}
#myplaces:hover
{ 
background-position: 0 -38px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<a id="home" href="#" title="Home"></a>
<a id="myplaces" href="#" title="My Places"></a>
</body>
```

I just couldn't figure out how to squash them onto the same line. I'm new to css and googling didn't get me any answers. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to float your links.
Add 'float:left' to both of your links' css.

Answer (score 3):

You can either float them (see answer by Jrod) or another alternative is to change from:

```
display: block;
```

to:

```
display: inline-block;
```

Comment: There will be a gap between the buttons with `inline-block`. It can be fixed (for example) by removing the whitespace between the links in the HTML. But, using `float: left` would be easier.

Comment: @thirtydot: I think there are pros and cons of both approaches. Certainly float: left is a very good solution, I upvoted jrod's answer myself for this reason.

Answer (score 1):

Simple: `display:block` makes them go on separate lines. Try `display:inline` instead.

Comment: Or remove display property from that css altogether as links are by default inline elements

Comment: Backgrounds, fixed heights etc. won't work (at least as they are currently implemented in the above code) if they are simply changed to "inline". See my answer which suggests moving to inline-block

Answer (score 0):

You should set `display` to `inline-block` and then `margin:0px;`.
Note that `display:inline` won't work.
And you should place the `<a>` tags on the same line.